Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'
when i builded a project by using taro template,
i use command,and got this error,did i missing install something?
this is the full error:
 pnpm run dev:weapp

> match-taro@1.0.0 dev:weapp /Users/vcc/Documents/match-taro
> npm run build:weapp -- --watch


> match-taro@1.0.0 build:weapp
> taro build --type weapp --watch

 Taro v4.0.6

Tips:
1. 预览模式生成的文件较大，设置 NODE_ENV 为 production 可以开启压缩。
Example:
$ NODE_ENV=production taro build --type weapp --watch
2. 建议开启持久化缓存功能，能有效提升二次编译速度，详情请参考: https://docs.taro.zone/docs/config-detail#cache。


提示  appid     touristappid
生成  工具配置  /Users/vcc/Documents/match-taro/dist/project.config.json
启动  开发者工具-项目目录  /Users/vcc/Documents/match-taro/dist

✖ Webpack
  Compiled with some errors in 321.27ms

编译  发现入口  src/app.ts
编译  发现页面  src/pages/index/index.vue
✖ Errors:

ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/.pnpm/babel-loader@8.2.1_@babel+core@7.26.0_webpack@5.78.0_@swc+core@1.3.96_/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: [BABEL] /Users/vcc/Documents/match-taro/node_modules/.pnpm/@tarojs+runtime@4.0.6/node_modules/@tarojs/runtime/dist/index.js: Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'
Require stack:
- /Users/vcc/Documents/match-taro/node_modules/.pnpm/babel-preset-taro@4.0.6_@babel+core@7.26.0_@babel+plugin-transform-typescript@7.25.9_@babel+c_ba2txpmkhpvrv6vgrznygms6uq/node_modules/babel-preset-taro/index.js
- /Users/vcc/Documents/match-taro/node_modules/.pnpm/@babel+core@7.26.0/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/module-types.js
- /Users/vcc/Documents/match-taro/node_modules/.pnpm/@babel+core@7.26.0/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/configuration.js
- /Users/vcc/Documents/match-taro/node_modules/.pnpm/@babel+core@7.26.0/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/index.js
- /Users/vcc/Documents/match-taro/node_modules/.pnpm/@babel+core@7.26.0/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js
- /Users/vcc/Documents/match-taro/node_modules/.pnpm/@tarojs+helper@4.0.6/node_modules/@tarojs/helper/dist/utils.js
- /Users/vcc/Documents/match-taro/node_modules/.pnpm/@tarojs+helper@4.0.6/node_modules/@tarojs/helper/dist/npm.js
- /Users/vcc/Documents/match-taro/node_modules/.pnpm/@tarojs+helper@4.0.6/node_modules/@tarojs/helper/dist/index.js
- /Users/vcc/Documents/match-taro/node_modules/.pnpm/@tarojs+helper@4.0.6/node_modules/@tarojs/helper/index.js
- /Users/vcc/Documents/match-taro/node_modules/.pnpm/@tarojs+cli@4.0.6/node_modules/@tarojs/cli/dist/util/index.js
- /Users/vcc/Documents/match-taro/node_modules/.pnpm/@tarojs+cli@4.0.6/node_modules/@tarojs/cli/bin/taro (While processing: "/Users/vcc/Documents/match-taro/node_modules/.pnpm/babel-preset-taro@4.0.6_@babel+core@7.26.0_@babel+plugin-transform-typescript@7.25.9_@babel+c_ba2txpmkhpvrv6vgrznygms6uq/node_modules/babel-preset-taro/index.js")
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at cachedFunction.next (<anonymous>)
    at loadPresetDescriptor.next (<anonymous>)
    at recursePresetDescriptors.next (<anonymous>)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at loadFullConfig.next (<anonymous>)
    at transform.next (<anonymous>)

→ Watching... [2024/10/29 10:17:00]

node:internal/process/promises:288
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "[object Array]".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
}

Node.js v18.20.3
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.

i try to search this kind of problem at Taro github but there is no answer
i check my install step and rebuild it step by step, it still can't work.
this is the step:
enter image description here
